# R there is no package called in a docker container

Tags: r, docker, installation, package

I have a docker image where I install several packages using the following lines:

```
FROM rocker/verse:4.0.3
... (some other installation details)
RUN install2.r --error \
    glmnet \
    ineq
    ...
```

However, I sporadically get error messages when running a container from that image where it seems like R cannot find that package:

```
Error in library(ineq) : there is no package called 'ineq'
```

If I create a new version of the container and manually open R and run it, I can never reproduce this error. Does anyone have any idea of how I can fix this (or what I should be looking for to reproduce this)?

Comment: I suspect there might be OS dependancies for specific R packages that aren't installed during the docker image build process. Can you include you Dockerfile with a base image that is accessible? Without that I think it's hard to give specific answers. It's also worth looking through your Docker build output to check whether the packages were installed successfully.

Comment: @JayAchar I updated it to show the base image that I'm using. I also looked through the logs and these packages get installed correctly:
`#12 31.14 trying URL 'https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest/src/contrib/glmnet_4.1.tar.gz'
#12 31.96 Content type 'binary/octet-stream' length 1997720 bytes (1.9 MB)
#12 31.96 ==================================================
#12 32.01 downloaded 1.9 MB`

Comment: The other thing to note is that it *usually* works and only throws an error sometimes. I think the hardest thing for me to deal with is the nondeterminism, so if you have any ideas on how to consistently reproduce this behavior that would be very much appreciated

Comment: Good chance the packagemanager at rstudio is down temporarily. You just have to try again later, or replace `install2.r` with repeated calls to `RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('package')"`

Answer (score 0):

Hitting the same "weird" behaviour..

My workaround was (I know its not elegant) using pacman instead of the library lines. What pacman does if it can't find the library it simply installs it. Which is obviously rude and anti-container pattern but at some point we need to move on :-/.. A big disadvantage here is that the container startup time could be huge if it is lost all of its packages and starts to re-install them

```
if(!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load("glmnet","ineq")
```